# Showing a Save As dialog box in Firefox

Tags: javascript, dojo

I am using dojo and javascript to create an application. In my application there is a file menu. On clicking the File>>Save As menu item,it should pop up a Save As dialog box.I'm using firefox.its not popping up the Save As dialog box.

Anyone pls help me

Answer (score 1):

This needs to be handled serverside as you need to set the mime-type and Content-Disposition header of the file you want to download, as you haven't said what serverside language you are using, I have provided the following example in PHP, but any serverside language you would be able to do the same. This will force the client to download the file, and in doing that if the user's browser is set up to not download automatically to a specific location, then the save-as pop-up window will appear.

```
 // make sure it's a file before doing anything!
 if(is_file($file_name))
 {

    /*
    Do any processing you'd like here:
        1.  Increment a counter
        2.  Do something with the DB
    3.  Check user permissions
        4.  Anything you want!
    */

     // required for IE
     if(ini_get('zlib.output_compression')) { ini_set('zlib.output_compression', 'Off');    }

     // get the file mime type using the file extension
     switch(strtolower(substr(strrchr($file_name,'.'),1)))
     {
         case 'pdf': $mime = 'application/pdf'; break;
         case 'zip': $mime = 'application/zip'; break;
         case 'jpeg':
         case 'jpg': $mime = 'image/jpg'; break;
         default: $mime = 'application/force-download';
     }
     header('Pragma: public');  // required
     header('Expires: 0');      // no cache
     header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
     header('Last-Modified: '.gmdate ('D, d M Y H:i:s', filemtime ($file_name)).' GMT');
     header('Cache-Control: private',false);
     header('Content-Type: '.$mime);
     header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.basename($file_name).'"');
     header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
     header('Content-Length: '.filesize($file_name));   // provide file size
     header('Connection: close');
     readfile($file_name);      // push it out
     exit();

 }
```